# Getting 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.BeansException' when starting tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying a **`Spring-MVC`** project SpringExample which is a simple Hello World example.There are no errors in the code and builds perfectly well, But when I start the tomcat to deploy the app I am getting the following exception :

```
SEVERE: Servlet /SpringExample threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.BeansException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1149)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Add org.springframework.beans-X.X.X.RELEASE.jar to Web App libraries. This should resolve the exception.